TIKZ Overlay Does Not Appear when PDFLATEX is run from Command Prompt
GOOD - When I run my TEX file in TexStudio (hit the play button), the tikz overlays (watermarks) appear in the PDF.
BAD - When I run my TEX file by executing it in a command prompt (pdflatex template.tex), only the tikz overlays for figures 1, 2, 3, 4 appear. The tikz overlays for the text and PDF files (table1 and table2) do not appear.
I examined the log files for both, and they were identical.
NOTE: I tried to delete most of the text for the sample code, but the following code runs.
\documentclass[12pt]{article}  
\usepackage{blindtext}
\usepackage[none]{hyphenat}
\usepackage{geometry}
\usepackage{mathptmx}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{sectsty}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{microtype}
\usepackage{pdfpages}
\usepackage{pdflscape}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\sisetup{round-mode = places, round-precision = 1, round-integer-to-decimal}
\usepackage{multicol} 
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{background}
\UseRawInputEncoding
\usepackage{array,ragged2e}
\usepackage [english]{babel}
\usepackage [autostyle, english = american]{csquotes}
\MakeOuterQuote{"}
\newcommand\tab[1][1cm]{\hspace*{#1}}
\columnsep= -4.in    
\sectionfont{\fontsize{12}{12}\selectfont}
\subsectionfont{\fontsize{12}{12}\selectfont}

\geometry{
    left=1in,
    right=1in,
    top=1in,
    bottom=1.25in
}       
            
\SetBgScale{9.0}\SetBgOpacity{0.15}\SetBgAngle{45}\SetBgColor{black}\SetBgContents{PRELIMINARY}

\begin{document}
 
\begin{center}
    \normalsize
    \textbf{SAMPLE TEXT}    
\end{center}






\newpage
\pagestyle{empty}
\newgeometry{
    left=0in,
    right=0in,
    top=0in,
    bottom=0in
}
\AddToShipoutPictureFG*{\begin{tikzpicture}[overlay, remember picture]\node [rotate=45, scale=9, opacity=0.15, black] at (current page.center) {PRELIMINARY};\end{tikzpicture}}
\begin{flushleft}
    \includegraphics{../plots/fig01_nfm_1B217_del.png}
\end{flushleft}

\newpage
\pagestyle{empty}
\newgeometry{
    left=0in,
    right=0in,
    top=0in,
    bottom=0in
}
\AddToShipoutPictureFG*{\begin{tikzpicture}[overlay, remember picture]\node [rotate=45, scale=9, opacity=0.15, black] at (current page.center) {PRELIMINARY};\end{tikzpicture}}
\begin{flushleft}
    \includegraphics{../plots/fig02_dod_1B217_del.png}
\end{flushleft}

\newpage
\pagestyle{empty}
\newgeometry{
    left=0in,
    right=0in,
    top=0in,
    bottom=0in
}
\AddToShipoutPictureFG*{\begin{tikzpicture}[overlay, remember picture]\node [rotate=45, scale=9, opacity=0.15, black] at (current page.center) {PRELIMINARY};\end{tikzpicture}}
\begin{flushleft}
    \includegraphics{../plots/fig03_tsfc_1B217_del.png}
\end{flushleft}




\newpage
\newgeometry{
    left=0in,
    right=0in,
    top=0in,
    bottom=0in
}
\begin{landscape}
\pagestyle{empty}
\AddToShipoutPictureFG*{\begin{tikzpicture}[overlay, remember picture]\node [rotate=135, scale=9, opacity=0.15, black] at (current page.center) {PRELIMINARY};\end{tikzpicture}}
    \begin{figure}[hbt!]
        \centering
        \includegraphics[angle=270]{../plots/fig04_bouncing_ball_1B217_del.png}     
    \end{figure}
\end{landscape}


\newpage
\pagestyle{empty}
\includepdf[pages=-]{../analysis/table1_1B217_del.pdf}


\newpage
\pagestyle{empty}
\includepdf[pages=-]{table2_1B217_del.pdf}

\end{document}


Because of the not available external files I cannot test it. But compiling from the command line should do the same as from within TeXstudio if you run the same commands. Have you, e.g., done all needed LaTeX runs. With overlay you usually need more than one LaTeX run. If I replace the image by image of package mwe, I've not problem.

Welcome! Please remove packages not required to reproduce the problem and use e.g. example-image-a etc. so other people can compile your code to test. Why do you have \UseRawInputEncoding?!! You cannot possibly need both blindtext and lipsum and shouldn't load either in your real document.

Yeah, my apologies...I'm picking this up from a co-worker that left and I have zero LaTex experience before this. I agree...it seems he went overboard on the number of packages.

Yes, reading through forums, I noticed people mention having to run LaTex twice, but when I examined the code, I couldn't understand how it was run "twice". This may be the key. How do I run it "twice"?

You're only adding the overlays to certain pages, so it isn't surprising they don't appear on the others. Don't use the starred form if you want it to apply to later pages, too.

To run it twice you just run it once and then do the same again ;).

So I put the "AddToShipoutPictureFG" line near the beginning of the TEX document (without the *asterisk), and then deleted all the other instances. The watermark appears on all the pages now.
Is there a way to stop applying the watermark midway through the document? The reason is I have one page that is rotated into a landscape orientation, but the watermark was applied before it was rotated. I would like to rotate the watermark 135 degrees for this page only (to align with the watermark on the other pages).

Clearing the picture is easy. Clearing it only for the current page seems ... less well supported.
The following code relies on implementation details of the shipout hooks provided by the LaTeX kernel. As such, it is not officially supported. It's exactly the kind of thing mortals are not meant to do ....
Caveat emptor
The dodgy part (i.e. the bit I'm not officially supposed to use) is \l__hook_return_tl. The double underscore marks this as internal. The other double underscores in what follows are fine. One is only in a comment and the others are all custom functions or variables, which complies with the official guidance (as far as I understand it, which is, admittedly, not very far but I think far enough for double underscores).
If we remove the code from the shipout picture, the kernel already catches it in a variable. It just doesn't seem to provide any public interface to access or reuse the value. So we copy the code to a variable of our own and then add it back into the shipout picture. We do this immediately, but we use a conditional test which initially fails. We then flip that test, right after the first time it fails, so that it succeeds on all subsequent occasions.
I've also saved your picture into a box so it does not need to be repeatedly rendered by tikz (which is slow). Use of the kernel's hooks makes placement slightly trickier, but means we don't need two compilations for the results to appear.
\documentclass [12pt]{book}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{pdflscape}
\ExplSyntaxOn
\bool_new:N \g__ryan_skipped_bool
% latex.ltx 5071-5100 def \__hook_gremove_code:nn 
\cs_new_protected:Npn \__ryan_hook_gremove_code_next:nn #1 #2
{
  \tl_if_exist:cF { g__ryan_hook_#1_code_tl }
  {
    \tl_new:c { g__ryan_hook_#1_code_tl }
  } 
  \hook_gremove_code:nn { #1 } { #2 }
  \tl_gset:cV  { g__ryan_hook_#1_code_tl } \l__hook_return_tl
  \bool_gset_false:N \g__ryan_skipped_bool
  \hook_gput_code:nnn { #1 } { #2 } {
    \bool_if:NT \g__ryan_skipped_bool
    {
      \tl_use:c { g__ryan_hook_#1_code_tl }
    }
    \bool_gset_true:N \g__ryan_skipped_bool
  } 
}
\cs_generate_variant:Nn \hook_gput_code:nnn { nnv }
\NewDocumentCommand \RemoveFrommHookNext { m m }
{
  \__ryan_hook_gremove_code_next:nn { #1 } { #2 }
}
\ExplSyntaxOff
\newsavebox{\prelimbox}
\sbox \prelimbox{%
  \begin{tikzpicture}[baseline=(n.center)] \node (n) [rotate=45, scale=9, opacity=0.15, black, inner sep=1pt] {PRELIMINARY};\end{tikzpicture}%
}
\AddToHook{shipout/foreground}[ryan/fg]
{%
  \put (0pt,-.5\paperheight) {\usebox\prelimbox}%
}

\usepackage{kantlipsum} % don't load this in your real document!
\begin{document}
\kant[1-10]

\begin{landscape}
\RemoveFrommHookNext {shipout/foreground} {ryan/fg}
\AddToHookNext {shipout/foreground}{%
  \put (.5\paperwidth,-.5\paperheight) {%
    \begin{tikzpicture}[baseline=(n.center)] \node (n) [rotate=90, scale=9, opacity=0.15, black, inner sep=1pt] {PRELIMINARY};\end{tikzpicture}%
  }%
}
\kant[11]
\end{landscape}

\kant[12-20]
\end{document}

I was convinced, incidentally, that there was out-of-the-box support for this but, if so, it is seriously elusive.
A safer strategy would be to include the conditional from the beginning, flip it on the landscape page and then flip it again on the next one, but that requires keeping track of what is on the following page. Or you could manually replace the original code, rather than saving it. Or put it into a macro and change the definition locally.
[That is, I just wanted there to be a way to do this.]
